# How to get index from firebase node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android application, and I am using Firebase database, 
this database showing an Items list.

This is my code.

```
private DatabaseReference root;
ListView elementList;
ArrayAdapter<mdlItem> adapter;
ArrayList<mdlItem> itemsList;
Context context;

private void loadFireDataBase() {
    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Offers");
    root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Add_Chat(dataSnapshot, "Add");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Add_Chat(dataSnapshot, "Edit");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Add_Chat(dataSnapshot , "Delete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Log.i(tag, "onCreateView");
    return creatList(inflater, container);
}

private View creatList(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container) {
    loadFireDataBase();
    context = getActivity();
    itemsList = new ArrayList<mdlItem>();
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.freg_main_content, container, false);
    elementList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.customListView);
    Collections.sort(itemsList, new Comparator<mdlItem>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(mdlItem data1, mdlItem data2) {
            if (data1.getOfferIndex() > data2.getOfferIndex())
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    });
    adapter = new offersArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.item_list_layout, itemsList);
    elementList.setAdapter(adapter);
    elementList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

private void Add_Chat(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String theCase) {
    Map<String, Object> question = null;
    try {
        String theOfferCode = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        question = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        mdlItem mdl = new mdlItem();
        mdl.setOfferCode(theOfferCode);
        mdl.setRestCode(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(question.get("itemCode"))));
        mdl.setRestName(question.get("itmeName").toString());
        switch (theCase) {
            case "Add":
                itemsList.add(mdl);
                break;
            case "Delete":
                itemsList.remove(mdl);
                break;
            case "Edit":
                //??
                break;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't get any node index through 'dataSnapshot' object, to control the list when I make Delete and Update.

And another thing how to use Add_Chat method to add the mdl item in the top of other items list.

I already catch the Edit, delete and add in the database root but I can't control how to use these events in the right way

I think I need to get the 'dataSnapshot' object to remove it or set an update on it, or if there is another solution

Can any one help me in this.

Comment: Do you mean key for the node's address?

Comment: yes when I delete node it sends this node to dataSnapshot, I want the index to delete it from itemsList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just For recording, This is the correct solution

```
  int index = -1;
            for (mdlItem item: itemsList) {
                if (item.getIndex() == mdl.getIndex()) {
                    index = itemsList.indexOf(item);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase snapshots are not index-based. If you need a mapping from the key in the database to the index in your adapter, you will need to maintain this mapping yourself.

For a simple version of this, have a look at the [`FirebaseArray`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java) class in the FirebaseUI library. It maintains a list of all snapshots that are currently in the array:

```
private final List<DataSnapshot> mSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then in the [`onChildAdded`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java#L66) methods adds, determines where the new item fits in the list and adds it:

```
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildKey) {
    int index = 0;
    if (previousChildKey != null) {
        index = getIndexForKey(previousChildKey) + 1;
    }

    mSnapshots.add(index, snapshot);
    notifyOnChildChanged(ChangeEventType.ADDED, snapshot, index, -1);
}
```

It does the equivalent for all other `onChild...` methods, so that it can look up the index for a specific key when needed with its [`getIndexForKey`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java#L113) method:

```
private int getIndexForKey(@NonNull String key) {
    int index = 0;
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : mSnapshots) {
        if (snapshot.getKey().equals(key)) {
            return index;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key not found");
}
```